# Demonstrate the Power of a Linux based Load balancing cluster

Tags: benchmarking, load-balancing, simulation, cluster-computing

I have to demonstrate the power of a cluster, i.e its advantage over a normal machine.

Is there any way I can show,to the layman that "If this had been done on a normal workstation, it would have taken X hours and with this cluster its the nth fraction of the x hrs taken"?

Please suggest some simulations/renders/computational tests that can give concrete figures to support the above argument.

Comment: This is more related to parallelization, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas: the [Beowulf.org](http://www.beowulf.org/) website, the [Linux High Performance Computing](http://linuxhpc.org/) website, the [Top500 Related Papers](http://top500.org/resources/papers) (not really Linux specific but there are some interesting data).